# StreamReader and streamwriter

Tags: c#

what mean this exception please ?

> Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was
>   used after being disposed.
>         at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write (System.String value) [0x00000]
>   in :0 
>         at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine (System.String value)
>   [0x00000] in :0 
>         at fichier.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x000bd] in
>   /Users/mediatun1/Projects/fichier/fichier/Main.cs:122

```
  System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 alg = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] md5val = alg.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes("TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST"));
    string output = Convert.ToBase64String(md5val);
    string pathPlainTextFile="/Users/mediatun1/Desktop/IAAT.xml"; 
    string pathCypheredTextFile="/Users/mediatun1/Desktop/IAA.xml";
    StreamReader fsPlainTextFile = File.OpenText(pathPlainTextFile);

    FileInfo t = new FileInfo(pathCypheredTextFile);
    StreamWriter Tex =t.CreateText();
    string input = null;
    while ((input = fsPlainTextFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {


                  byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);



                RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

                // Définit le mode utilisé
                rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

                // Crée le chiffreur AES - Rijndael
                ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(md5val,null);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                // Ecris les données chiffrées dans le MemoryStream
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();


                // Place les données chiffrées dans un tableau d'octet
                byte[] CipherBytes = ms.ToArray();


                ms.Close();
                cs.Close();

                // Place les données chiffrées dans une chaine encodée en Base64

    Tex.WriteLine (Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes));

                Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes));
            Tex.Close();    


    }
```

Comment: Try to put more details into the post and clearly explain what you are trying to do and what fails, please.

Comment: Where is line 122 in the code? This is what is throwing the error. It means exactly what it says, but I am not yet sure where this is a problem from.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `Tex.WriteLine (Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes));` is line 122 of `main.cs` file? Because I suspect it's not and the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

You have `Tex.Close();`  inside your loop. So after iteration 1 the StreamWriter is closed.

Generally `Streams` that are opened outside the loop should be closed outside the loop.

Comment: A using-statement will help with that, certainly. =)

Comment: Well done, I completely missed that one. A good reason for the code to be improved for readability thou I guess

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with closing your streams to early.I cannot quite work it out on your code, perhaps if you change order of

```
ms.Close();
cs.Close();
```

to...

```
cs.Close();
ms.Close();
```

it may work

**EDIT:** As jaywayco has pointed out, the failing code is definitely going to be due to Tex being closed inside the loop. I had completely missed this whilst trying to understand the code

However, you really need to tidy all this up. You should use "using" statements for your streams as this will close them automatically when finished with. Something like....

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(...))
{
   using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(...))
   {
      //code for cs stream in here
   }
}
```

Comment: ino work my bro , i ca just write the first line  but next i can't write the next line